# Convert nested json to CSV with keys javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, csv, export-to-csv

All
I am trying to convert nested JSON into CSV with object key as group identifier in csv.
this is the JSON I am working on

```
    "Name": "Name",
    "LoyaltyNumber": "Loyalty Number",
    "LoyaltySaved": "Loyalty Items Were Saved",
    "LoyaltyDeleted": "Loyalty Item Was Deleted",
    "Add": "Add ",
    "Loyalty": " Loyalty",
    "DeleteLoyalty": "Delete Loyalty"
  },
  "LoyaltyViewer": {
    "AirlineLoyalty": "Airline Loyalty",
    "HotelLoyalty": "Hotel Loyalty",
    "CarLoyalty": "Car Loyalty",
    "RailLoyalty": "Rail Loyalty"
  },
```

my current script for conversion is

```
function toCSV(json) {
    json = Object.values(json);
    let csv = '';
    const keys = (json[0] && Object.keys(json[0])) || [];
    csv += keys.join(',') + '\n';
    for (let line of json) {
      csv += keys.map((key) => line[key]).join(',') + '\n';
    }
    FileSystem.writeFileSync('./destination3.csv', csv);
    return csv;
 
}
```

but the result is not what is expected result should be similar to this

[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxar7.png)

but i am getting it like this

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1m0G.png)

Can you please point me in a right direction , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use papa parse this one is a very powerful tool to handle csv and json data

https://www.papaparse.com/docs#json-to-csv

it has npm and cdn both.